# Why is there a white line on UISearchController when click on the search bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, navigationbar, uisearchcontroller

[image]

[image]
[image]

As you can see from the picture, there is a white line when you search bar is click. I had try to set the background image to UIImage and clear all the shadow image but still this white line keep coming out when the search bar click and animate.

Pooja Gupta solution result:

[image]

This is the code that i use to customise the navigation bar

```
 [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:barColor];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:buttonColor];
```

Comment: Does your navigation controller include a bottom toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same issue. When scrolling down scrollview there was a white line between navi-bar and search bar. By inspecting UI hierarchy I found out that there is a gap between them.

The color of the gap would be other view's background color, like tableview, collection, or webview. In my project case there is a webview. So I put a backgoround color same as navigation bar's tint color on webview's scrollview. Then problem solved!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add border as your background color

```
 UIColor bgColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // This is your background color.     
_searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
_searchBar.layer.borderColor = bgColor.CGColor;
```

Comment: i try your solution, you can view the result above. The colour a bit off what can i do ?

Comment: Can you please show the searchbar attributes(you can get it by searchbar attribute inspector) and any extra code to set the searchbar

Comment: I have the same results, a white line when I navigate back to the view that has the searbar; when I set the searchbar borders to zero or even to match the navigation bars backroad color, I still see the white line while the searcbar is animated to become visible; after the animation has completed, there is no while line visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to customise the colour through the Storyboard and not from the code. You see that the white row disappear (I don't know how but it does).

See the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGlJu.png